# OpenLayers 3 - Add scale line out of map

Tags: css, openlayers-3

How to add a scaleline out of map area?
My HTML:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="scaleline"></div>
```

and javascript code for adding scaleline:

```
var scale = new ol.control.ScaleLine({
    target: document.getElementById("scaleline")
});
map.addControl(scale);
```

It sounds a CSS problem, but how do i configure css for div "scaleline" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work. See in action in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2te0r10k/)

```
var scaleLineControl = new ol.control.ScaleLine({
  target: document.getElementById('scaleline')   
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([scaleLineControl])
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it works. but one more problem. why it is placed at the end of page? I mean 'scaleline' div is right after 'map' div but scaleline appears at the end of page (and in your fiddle, after <select>).

Comment: It is styled by Openlayers CSS in `position: absolute; bottom: 8px` (for `.ol-scale-line`). You can override it if needed

Comment: Would you help me to do that? I've played with various css attributes but still i have problem moving scaleline from inside map to right after map. I've also used className property of ScaleLine control but no help. My map width is 100%.

Comment: `.ol-scale-line { position: relative; }`